# Missing method exceptions with System.Collections.Immutable and System.Reflection.Metadata

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, missingmethodexception

I'm trying to debug the following error being thrown in my solution.

> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found:
>   'System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1
>   System.Reflection.Metadata.MetadataReader.GetBlobContent(System.Reflection.Metadata.BlobHandle)'.

It seems as though the versions of `System.Collections.Immutable` and `System.Reflection.Metadata` are incorrect in some way, but I have no idea how to debug this.  I've been checking versions, clearing NuGet caches, and restarting VS, to no avail.  What else can I try to fix this?

Comment: Well where are you calling this method?  It's hard to help when we can't see your code.

Comment: It does not seem like I am calling this method anywhere, I have searched VS for the method signature.  I would have added the code in question if it existed.

Comment: I suggest using ILSpy to open each assembly and check their dependencies.  You likely have a version mismatch somewhere, e.g. you're using A 1.0 and B 1.2, but B depends on A 1.1.

Comment: When you say open each assembly, do you mean open each DLL?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I see that I am requiring different versions of System.Collections.Immutable in my `obj/` and `objd/` folders.  Could this be problematic?

Comment: It can be an issue, but isn't necessarily.  You might try using an assembly binding redirect.